Find the angle $x$ in the triangle $APQ $ below
iF $AB=AQ$ calcule $x^o$
(Answer: $30^o$)

I try:
$\triangle ABQ: \angle ABQ \cong \angle BQA  = 90^o -2\alpha$
$\triangle ABC: \angle B = 180^o - 4\alpha -(60^o -2\alpha) =120^o -2\alpha $
$ \angle CQB = 180^o -(90^o-\alpha) = 90^o +2\alpha $
$ \angle APC =\angle x + \angle QPC =  180^o - \alpha - (60^o -2\alpha)= 120^o + \alpha$
$\angle BPA = 60^o -\alpha$
How do I finish?

@CalvinLin Exterior Angle $\triangle QBA$

Thanks for fixing the error.

As in the figure below, let $R$ be the third vertex of the equilateral triangle $AQR$ (with $R$ on the same side as $B$, with respect to $AC$).


$ARB$ is isosceles by construction and the hypotheses, which implies that $\measuredangle ARB = \measuredangle ABR = 60^\circ + 2\alpha$.
Since $\measuredangle ABC = 120^\circ-2\alpha$ from the hypotheses, we have that $\measuredangle RBC = 180^\circ$, so that $R$, $B$, and $C$ are in fact aligned.
Angle chasing on $ARP$ shows that $\measuredangle PAR = \measuredangle APR = 60^\circ-\alpha$, so that the triangle is isosceles.
By 1., 3., and the construction, $QPR$ is isosceles as well, with $\measuredangle QPR = 90^\circ-\alpha$.
By 3. and 4., we have $$\boxed{\measuredangle APQ = 30^\circ.}$$


Excellent, can explain better "Exterior Angle Theorem on ABC implies that R, B, and C are aligned?

@petaarantes I rephrased point 2., hopefully making it clearer.

Thanks for explanation

You've made a good start. I assume the angles in your diagram were provided with the problem. Thus, as you've determined, $\measuredangle ABP = 120^{\circ} - 2\alpha$ and $\measuredangle BPA = 60^{\circ} - \alpha$. Using the Law of Sines with $\triangle ABP$, plus the formulas in Angle sum and difference identities, gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert AP\rvert}{\sin(120^{\circ} - 2\alpha)} & = \frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{\sin(60^{\circ} - \alpha)} \\
\frac{\lvert AP\rvert}{\lvert AB\rvert} & = \frac{\sin(2(60^{\circ} - \alpha))}{\sin(60^{\circ} - \alpha)} \\
& = 2\cos(60^{\circ} - \alpha) \\
& = 2(\cos(60^{\circ})\cos\alpha + \sin(60^{\circ})\sin\alpha) \\
& = \cos\alpha + \sqrt{3}\sin\alpha
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Next, using these formulas with $\triangle APQ$ leads to
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert AP\rvert}{\sin(180^{\circ} - (\alpha + x))} & = \frac{\lvert AQ\rvert}{\sin(x)} \\
\frac{\lvert AP\rvert}{\lvert AQ\rvert} & = \frac{\sin(\alpha + x)}{\sin(x)} \\
& = \frac{\sin\alpha\cos(x) + \cos\alpha\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Because $\lvert AB\rvert = \lvert AQ\rvert$ is given, we can equate the RHS of the above $2$ sets of equations to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\cos\alpha + \sqrt{3}\sin\alpha & = \frac{\sin\alpha\cos(x) + \cos\alpha\sin(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
\cos\alpha\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}\sin\alpha\sin(x) & = \sin\alpha\cos(x) + \cos\alpha\sin(x) \\
\sqrt{3}\sin\alpha\sin(x) - \sin\alpha\cos(x) & = 0 \\
\sin\alpha(\sqrt{3}\sin(x) - \cos(x)) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $\sin\alpha \neq 0$, we must instead have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{3}\sin(x) - \cos(x) & = 0 \\
\sqrt{3}\sin(x) & = \cos(x) \\
\tan(x) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
x & = 30^{\circ}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Thank you my friend, wouldn't there be a geometric solution, perhaps by constructing auxiliary lines...? Without using so much trigonometry?

@petaarantes You're welcome. Regarding a geometric solution, I don't offhand see any way to do that. Note that with the $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle APQ$ each having $2$ side lengths equal to each other, and "known" angles in terms of the $2$ variables $\alpha$ and $x$, then using the law of sines seemed to me to be a reasonable choice to check on. Nonetheless, I will try to determine a geometric type solution instead, and I hope that whether it be me or somebody else, you'll get one.


Another geometric approach: In picture CE is the bisector of angle ACB. S is mid point of arc BC so $MS\bot BC$. We have:
$\overset {\huge\frown}{BS}=4\alpha $
$\Rightarrow\angle MBC=\angle MCB$
$\angle MBC=90-4\alpha\Rightarrow \angle BCU=45-2\alpha$
Finally:
$\angle ACU=60-2\alpha-(45-2\alpha)=15^o\Rightarrow \angle APQ=30^o$

Thanks for help
